# $a=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i 10^i$. Prove, that $3|a$ only when $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i \equiv_3 0$

Tags: summation, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Let$$a=a_n 10^n + a_{n-1} 10^{n-1} + ... + a_1 10 + a_0 $$
And $$ a_i \in \{0,...,9\} \text{ for } i=0,1,...,n $$

1. Prove, that:
   $$3|a \Leftrightarrow a_n+a_{n-1} + ... + a_1 + a_0 \equiv_3 0$$
2. Prove, that:
   $$11|a \Leftrightarrow (a_1+a_3+...) - (a_0+a_2+...) \equiv_{11} 0$$

I don't know how to do either 1 or 2. A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$10\equiv 1 \mod 3$$
$$10^k\equiv 1 \mod 3$$

$$10\equiv -1\mod 11$$
$$10^k \equiv (-1)^k \mod 11$$